# Additional log partition with buildroot

Tags: partition, ext4, buildroot

I made my Linux with Buildroot, and I would like to add an additional partition what can be mounted and store log files on it.
I use

> pc_x86_64_efi_defconfig

and my

> genimage-efi.cfg

is the following:

```
image efi-part.vfat {
        vfat {
                file EFI {
                        image = "efi-part/EFI"
                }

                file bzImage {
                        image = "bzImage"
                }
        }

        size = 16352K # 16MB - 32KB
}

image disk.img {
        hdimage {
                partition-table-type = "gpt"
        }

        partition boot {
                image = "efi-part.vfat"
                partition-type-uuid = U
                offset = 32K
                bootable = true
        }

        partition root {
                partition-type-uuid = 44479540-f297-41b2-9af7-d131d5f0458a
                partition-uuid = UUID_TMP
                image = "rootfs.ext2"
        }

        partition log {
                partition-type-uuid = L
                size = 500M
        }
}
```

the part I added is the partition log.
When I'm in the system I can see the

> /dev/sda3

but I can't mount it.
In

> dmesg
> I see the error it can't be mounted, use GNU gparted to fix it

Can someone help me out what I miss in the cfg file.
Looking forward to your help.